# Is there a way to conditionally add to an array in one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have str1 and str2.  str1 may or not be an empty string, and I want to construct an array like:

```
str1 = ""
str2 = "bar"
["bar"]
```

or

```
str1 = "foo"
str2 = "bar"
["foo", "bar"]
```

I can only figure out a way to do this on two lines right now but I know there must be a way to do it one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```ruby
[str1, str2].reject {|x| x==''}
# ...or...
[str1, str2].reject &:empty?
```

Comment: Or: [str1, str2].reject( &:empty? )

Answer (score 32):

In ruby 1.9

```
[*(str1 unless str1.empty?), str2]
```

In ruby 1.8

```
[(str1 unless str1.empty?), str2].compact
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Definitely my favorite answer!

Comment: Note that the proposed answer for Ruby 1.9 has issues with a hash where as the `compat` approach does not - [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69398659/3216868).

Answer (score 6):

[Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-tap)

```
[:starting_element].tap do |a|
  a << true if true
  a << false if false
  a << :for_sure
end
# => [:starting_element, true, :for_sure]
```

So in one line

```
[].tap { |a| [foo, bar].each { |thing| a << thing unless thing.blank? } }
[bar].tap { |a| a << bar unless foo.blank? }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **delete_if**:

```
['', 'hola'].delete_if(&:empty?)
```

If you're using Rails, you can replace **empty?** by **blank?**

```
['', 'hola'].delete_if(&:blank?)
```

or use a block:

```
['', 'hola'].delete_if{ |x| x == '' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that sawa's [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065567/3216868) for Ruby 1.9 (currently the answer with the most votes) has issues when used with a hash - as follows;

```rb
> [*({foo: 1} if true), {foo: 2}]
[
    [0] [
        [0] :foo,
        [1] 1
    ],
    [1] {
        :foo => 2
    }
]
```

Note that the compact example works as you would expect;

```rb
[({foo: 1} if true), {foo: 2}].compact
[
    [0] {
        :foo => 1
    },
    [1] {
        :foo => 2
    }
]
```

Comment: `[*([foo: 1] if true), {foo: 2}]` works for hashes as expected -- you get a list with the hash, which you can splat for the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Another way,

```
(str1.present? ? str1 : []) + [str2]
```

Comment: most easiily understandable in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more concise version of Cyril's answer:

`Array.new.tap do |array|
  if condition
    array << "foo"
  end
end`

Answer (score 1):

A more compact way to do this is using [`presence`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object:presence), which returns the object if present, or `nil` if not.

`nil` values can then be stripped with `.compact`:

```
[str1.presence, str2].compact
```

or even better, the magical `*` splat operator:

```
[*str1.presence, str2]
```

(And yes, pun was intended)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary statement:

```
ary = (str1.empty?) ? [ str2 ] : [ str1, str2 ]

str1 = ''; str2 = 'bar'
(str1.empty?) ? [ str2 ] : [ str1, str2 ] #=> ["bar"]
str1 = 'foo'; str2 = 'bar'
(str1.empty?) ? [ str2 ] : [ str1, str2 ] #=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? It does exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: It does suit the specific example given by the OP, but isn't flexible enough to handle any variations (eg answer by @Yogesh can conditionally add `str1` to any array)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_array = [str1, str2].find_all{|item| item != ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a way, I feel like there are 2 different questions being asked:

1. Is there a way to conditionally add to an array in one line?
2. How do I achieve this specific task.

Regarding question #1:
Other people have already offered a lot of good options.  One that I didn't see specifically mentioned though is that you can technically use a semicolon (`;`) as an inline statement separator and basically write whatever you want on a single line of code.  For example:

```
array = []; if x; array << a; elsif y; array << b; else; array << c; end; array
```

Regarding question #2:
Here's a fun option to to add to the list.  Use the `chomp(separator)`, `split`, and `reverse` methods.

```
str1 = ""
str2 = "bar"

"#{str2},#{str1}".chomp(",").split(",").reverse
#=>  ["bar"]

str1 = "foo"
str2 = "bar"

"#{str2},#{str1}".chomp(",").split(",").reverse
#=>  ["foo", "bar"]
```

`string.chomp(substring)` with and without `reverse` can be super handy ways to format string results that would otherwise need some conditional statements to handle the same operation somewhere else in the chain.

Answer (score -1):

You could monkey-patch Aray pr Enumerable and provide a conditional adding method.

```
module Array
 def add_if(object, condition=true)
   self << object if condition
   return self
 end
end
```

That way, it would be chainable, preserving most space in line.
`array = [].add(:class, is_given?).add(object, false) #etc`